# Accessing form elements from external javascript file

Tags: javascript, forms

this seems like a simple thing and I would really like to understand this a little more. Here is my issue.

I have a select with a few different options sitting inside a form. I need a variable that is going to hold which option is selected so that from there I can do different things based on what is selected.

Here is my html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form method="get">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <p>
                    Please choose your class:
                </p>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name= "classSelect" id="classSelect" size = "3">
                        <option value = "CS211" selected = "selected">CS-211</option>
                        <option value = "CS111">CS-111</option>
                        <option value = "CS275">CS-275</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form
    </body>
</html>
```

And then in my javascript file I simply want to declare a global variable:

```
var currentSelection = document.forms[0].classSelect.selectedIndex;
```

Now that currentSelection is always null and I am not sure why.

Comment: Perhaps use JQuery and do $("#classSelect").val()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOM isn't yet rendered when you're setting the variable. Either wait for the DOM to fire its ready event or set the script to run after the document has loaded. Here's a solution:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // run this code on load
};
```

Note that this will overwrite the previous onload function. If you have jQuery available, you should do this instead to avoid any overwrites:

```
$(window).load(function() {});
```

These variants also work:

```
$(function() {});
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

Comment: What is the best way to accomplish what I need to do?

Comment: I've modified the answer.

Comment: currentSelection is still undefined. I'm expecting it to initially have the value zero because I made the first element in my selection list selected by default and it should change to one if I hit the second element, etc. Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: I've figured out the current problem, I added a onchange event for my selector which called a function that does this: 
    x=document.getElementById("classSelect").selectedIndex;
    y=document.getElementById("classSelect").options;

I guess I was confused because you can't just define variables like that globally outside of a function?

Comment: You can define variables like that, but you might be accessing them before they are assigned a value.